# apache solr showing a maximum of 11789 results

Tags: apache, solr

I am inserting documents which are 8000000 in total but upon inserting I can see solr taking in only 11789 documents and starts overwriting the others. So after the whole inserting procedure I can see only  11789 document in solr.

I am new to solr.
Kindly help.
Thank you

Below is my code. And the settings for autocommit are default settings. 
Sorry for posting the code late.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class smartGalleries implements Callable {

    @Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext ctx) throws Exception {
    MuleMessage msg = ctx.getMessage();

    HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8984/solr");


    ArrayList<SolrInputDocument> docList = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    for (int a = 0; a < 12; a++) {

        File opFile = new File("/input/output" + a + ".txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(opFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        JSONArray jsa = (JSONArray) parse.parse(br);


        for (int i = 0; i < jsa.size(); i++) {

            // INSERTING THE WHOLE STRUCTURE IN MONGODB

            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsa.get(i);
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

            // CONVERSION TO GALLERY OBJECT




            JSONObject metadata = (JSONObject) object.get("metadata");

            ArrayList<Asset> assetList = new ArrayList<Asset>();

            JSONArray gis = (JSONArray) object.get("gallery_item_set");

            for (int k = 0; k < gis.size(); k++) {

                JSONObject gisobj = (JSONObject) gis.get(k);
                Asset asset = new Asset();

                SolrInputDocument assetDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

                if (gisobj.containsKey("content")) {
                    JSONObject content = (JSONObject) gisobj.get("content");

                    asset.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(content.get("height")
                            .toString()));
                    asset.setWidth(Integer.parseInt(content.get("width")
                            .toString()));
                    asset.setOrientation(content.get("orientation")
                            .toString());
                    asset.setId((content.get("guid").toString()));
                    assetDoc.addField("height", asset.getHeight());
                    assetDoc.addField("width", asset.getWidth());
                    assetDoc.addField("orientation",
                            asset.getOrientation());
                    assetDoc.addField("id", asset.getId());

                    Date createdImage = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .parse(content.get("created_at").toString());
                    Date modifiedImage = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .parse(content.get("modified_at").toString());
                    Date publishedImage = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .parse(content.get("published_at").toString());

                    asset.setCreatedDate(createdImage);
                    asset.setModifiedDate(modifiedImage);
                    asset.setPublishedDate(publishedImage);
                    assetDoc.addField("createdDate", asset
                            .getCreatedDate().toString());
                    assetDoc.addField("publishedDate", asset
                            .getPublishedDate().toString());
                    assetDoc.addField("modifiedDate", asset
                            .getModifiedDate().toString());
                    if (content.containsKey("attribution_text")) {

                        asset.setCredit(content.get("attribution_text")
                                .toString());
                        assetDoc.addField("credit", asset.getCredit());

                    }

                    if (content.containsKey("description")) {
                        asset.setDescription(content.get("description")
                                .toString());
                        assetDoc.addField("description",
                                asset.getDescription());
                    }

                    if (content.containsKey("metadata")) {
                        JSONObject contentmeta = (JSONObject) content
                                .get("metadata");
                        if (contentmeta.containsKey("keyword")) {
                            JSONObject contentmetakey = (JSONObject) contentmeta
                                    .get("keyword");
                            JSONArray unknownSet = (JSONArray) contentmetakey
                                    .get("unknown_set");
                            ArrayList<String> imgKeyword = new ArrayList<String>();
                            if (unknownSet.size() != 0) {

                                for (int l = 0; l < unknownSet.size(); l++) {
                                    JSONObject text = (JSONObject) unknownSet
                                            .get(l);
                                    if (text.get("text__t") != null) {
                                        imgKeyword.add(text.get("text__t")
                                                .toString());

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            asset.setKeywords(imgKeyword);
                            assetDoc.addField("keywords",
                                    asset.getKeywords());
                        }
                    }
                }

                JSONObject gismeta = (JSONObject) gisobj.get("metadata");
                if (gismeta != null) {
                    if (gismeta.containsKey("caption")) {
                        if (gismeta.get("caption") != null)
                            asset.setCaption(gismeta.get("caption")
                                    .toString());
                        assetDoc.addField("caption",
                                asset.getCaption());

                    }
                }

                asset.setPosition(Integer.parseInt(gisobj.get("position")
                        .toString()));
                assetDoc.addField("position", asset.getPosition());

                docList.add(assetDoc);


                server.add(assetDoc);


                System.out.println(doc);

            }



            server.commit();





        }


        server.setConnectionTimeout(100);
    }


    return msg;
}
}
```

and the error::

```
Exception stack is:
1. No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect (java.net.SocketException)
  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
2. IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8983/solr (org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException)
  org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer:566 (null)
3. Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{filetestFlow1.component.1935247117}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter:348 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? What version of Solr? How many servers? Do your documents have an id field? If your documents have the same id, then they will be overwritten. Are you sure these documents are getting indexed? In your SolrConfig file enable this feature  
                <infoStream file="INFOSTREAM-${solr.core.name}.txt">true</infoStream>. And then check this file to see if there are any errors during indexing.

Comment: what method of insertion are you using? Via csv import, solrj add or something else? What kind of commit settings do you have? Is autocommit or commit by the inserting client?